# Difference between login.event and logout.event in liferay

Tags: events, action, hook, liferay

I hooked up these two events with one class and my question is How can I recognize when the class is called by `login.event` and when by `logout.event`.

My class extends `Action`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that comes to my mind: Implement the two events in different classes. If you desperately want the implementation to be in a single class, delegate to it from the action classes.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer also the solution from Olaf, to take two separate classes. But if you have hard requirements to use olny one class, then you can try to recognise the event type about the called stack trace.

```
private void printStackTrace() {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTrace) {
        System.out.println(stackTraceElement.getClassName() + "." + stackTraceElement.getMethodName());
    }
}
```

Comment: ouch - I can't imagine any hard requirement (that I consier valid) to go this way. While technically correct, I'd strongly argue against it. But then, you're suggesting the same already.